# In REST, how to respond to POST of a sub-entity of which there can only be one, and one already exists?

Tags: api, rest, api-design, aggregateroot

I have a `vehicles` resource as the root entity of an aggregate. Each vehicle can have zero or one `engines` as a sub-resource/entity.

If vehicle #947 exists, but doesn't have an engine, I can say:

```
POST /vehicles/947/engines         /* create an engine with id=0 */

GET /vehicles/947/engines          /* read an array bearing a single engine at index 0 with id=0*/

GET /vehicles/947/engines/0        /* read the engine explicitly by id */
```

What should I return if the above have been executed, but then subsequently this is executed?

```
POST vehicles/947/engines
```

I already have an engine for vehicle 947, and I can't allow another. What status should be returned?

Some possibilities I looked at:

- "**403 Forbidden**" - This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) indicates a "403 Forbidden" should be issued. However, [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) seems to indicate that "403 Forbidden" is all about authority problems.
- "**406 Not Acceptable**" - [Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406), this seems to be more targeted at situations caused by header restrictions.
- "**409 Conflict**" - [Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409), hmmm, maybe.

Should I be structuring the REST path differently? I think the shown structure makes sense. `Engines` is truly an entity of its own, and is attached to a vehicle. Each engine has a ton of attributes that I really don't want to just throw into the vehicle; the attributes belong with the engine.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you can only have exactly 1 of some resource, wouldn't `PUT` on a stable url be more appropriate here?

Comment: @Evert, I'm sure you're aware of this, but for the sake of other readers: traditionally, a PUT doesn't create, it updates. So both a POST and a PUT are needed here. My concern, though, is if someone unwittingly does a POST of an engine where an engine already exists. Clearly they should have done a PUT (after GETting the engine), but if they instead blindly do a POST, what should my service return?

Comment: this is actually not correct. `PUT` replaces or created. It should be the first choice for creating resources for which the client can know the target uri in advance. `POST` is more often used for creation, but solely because in many cases you'll want the server-side to be able to determine the new resource uri, maybe because you're using an auto-incrementing key for example.

Comment: `PUT` is the better choice for this case, I'd invite you to read the relevant bits of the HTTP specification as it will cover this.

Comment: Url structure wise, I would simply in your case support `GET` and `PUT` on `/vehicles/947/engine`. It's very strange that you'd put an 'engines' collection in here if there's only ever going to be one.

Comment: Good feedback. Thanks @Evert.

Answer (score 1):

First point: the [IANA status code registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) lists the authoritative reference for the semantics of each status code.  Most of the common ones are defined by the latest HTTP specification; today, that means [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5).

Second point: status codes are metadata, providing hints about response semantics to general purpose components (like web browsers, or caches).  Using status codes in the standard ways means that our API resources look just like any other page on the web.

In other words, we can answer questions like this by considering "what would a web server do?" or "how does the status code change the behavior of general purpose components?"

Reasonable choices for your example:

- [403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) "I understood your request, but I refuse to authorize it."
- [405](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) "This resource doesn't support this method right now"
- [409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) "This edit conflicts with the current state of the resource"

405 is "cacheable by default", which is one way to tell them apart; in addition, that status code requires an [Allow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.4.1) header to describe the currently supported methods.

Otherwise, there isn't a lot of difference between these codes - browsers aren't going to treat them differently, same with caches.

One additional point to consider is the impact of the codes you chose on your operators, or any body else who ends up reading access logs.  403 in an access log can mean a number of different things, where 409 has fewer options consistent with its standard semantics.

> Should I be structuring the REST path differently?

Maybe.  REST doesn't care about *entities*, it cares about *documents* ([resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) being a generalization of documents, for the most part).

So is the document about the engine the same document as the document about the vehicle, or should they be two separate documents (perhaps connected by a link)?  Should they be cached together (meaning that invalidating one document also invalidates the other), or separately (one document changes frequently, the other rarely)?

It's the same sort of trade off we make when deciding whether to put java script in a script tag in an HTML document vs having a link from the HTML document to the javascript.  Either answer can make sense under the right conditions.

The URI spellings are fine.  If there's only ever going to be one engine resource, then you might consider using the identifier `/vehicles/947/engine`.  It can also make sense to store engine documents in an engine document collection: `/engines/947`.  If you expect to be using [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) to identify other documents, then it can be more convenient to have the identifiers in the same hierarchy.

Comment: Good feedback @VoiceofUnreason. You and @Evert seem to agree on making `/vehicles/947/engine` singular. Moreover, you both suggest considering moving to `/engines/947`. I'll definitely consider. Much thanks.

Comment: VoiceofUnreason and @Evert, I'd like your further thoughts on this: One difficulty in moving to the `/engines/947` structure is that, for the engine associated with vehicle 947, I still can't `POST /engines`, but rather I must first `GET /engines/947` and then `PUT /engines/947`. That is, the requester must control the id, and ensure no unintentional overwriting. The structure `GET /vehicles/947/engine` and `PUT /vehicles/947/engine` seems a bit more natural. I appreciate your help.